# rewriting a URL with not mandatory parts

Tags: .htaccess, helicontech

Currently i have the following rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/order/([^/]*)[/]? /order_form.php?lang=$1&plan=$2 [QSA,L]
```

which translates into:
/en/order/
OR
/en/order/plan1/

Which works fine. However, i'd like to add something on the back. Something like plan1-companyname.

But i can't seem to get it working.

i tried:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/order/([^/]*)-companyname[/]? /order_form.php?lang=$1&plan=$2 [QSA,L]
```

but this makes it mandatory. when i include brackets

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/order/([^/]*)[-bucket/]? /order_form.php?lang=$1&plan=$2 [QSA,L]
```

it doesnt work either. Can someone fix me up or kickstart me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use parentheses instead of square brackets:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/order/([^/]*?)(-companyname)?/?$ /order_form.php?lang=$1&plan=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Additionally, you need to make your second `([^/]*)` grouping non-greedy.

Comment: You sire, made my day shine. Thanks alot :-)